# Private Tor network, socket explanation

Tags: relays, private

I recently made a private Tor network using virtual machines (with [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20180711234037/https://fengy.me/prog/2015/01/09/private-tor-network/)). The network is composed of three nodes:

- **goupix** with the ip address 172.26.145.**31**
- **grodoudou** with the ip address 172.26.145.**32**
- **grolem** with the ip address 172.26.145.**33**

Moreover, **grolem** runs a directory server too.

The problem is, I have unexpected and yet unexplained opened socket on my VM's.

The nodes seem to communicate with each other, as shown by the following screenshot:

[image: Opened sockets on my machines]

Why 172.26.145.31 communicate with 172.26.145.32 ? I don't have any client requesting the building of a circuit, and yet two nodes communicate with each other.

Here you can see another screenshot of a tcpdump on goupix ( 172.26.145.31 ) communicating with grodoudou ( 172.26.145.32 ) :

[image: Tcpdump on goupix]

The length seems to be the size of Tor cells if you remove the headers.

Also, why there is a UDP socket "listening" on my machines, doesn't Tor communicate only via TCP? I didn't find any information on this.

Comment: Relays have to download new consensuses too. There will always be a little background traffic, even there are no clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, why there is a UDP socket "listening" on my machines

I think it's DNS (you can add DNSPort 5353 option in torrc and you will see).

> The problem is, i have unexpected and yet unexplained opened socket on my VM's.

Look at your torrc for the following option "ORPort". It's external port for incoming tor connections. (in your torrc it uses 5000 port if you copy and paste torrc from guide, ofc).

Tor manual:

> Advertise this port to listen for connections from Tor clients and
>   servers. This option is required to be a Tor server. Set it to "auto"
>   to have Tor pick a port for you. Set it to 0 to not run an ORPort at
>   all. This option can occur more than once. (Default: 0)

Comment: I understand, but the network is private and not connected to the internet. Also, I don't have any client requesting the building of a circuit.